# Suspend on elementary Juno has been broken

Tags: release-juno, suspend, power, dell

Suspend was working perfectly fine until yesterday. I mean, closing the lid, pushing the power button and selecting suspend from the power menu was well, suspending the system.

As of today, doing any of those things reboot the system.

Any clues?

What: Dell XPS 9550 with 1.9.0 BIOS (latest)

How: elementary OS 5.0 with everything updated through AppCenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved itself with no input from my part.

Comment: Actually, the problem showed up again (but also went away), randomly. Anyone else?

Comment: Still happening from now and then, anyone else?